# mapping between 2 collections in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, set, mapping, project, lookup

I would like to do a mapping between 2 collections and modify the value of a property of collection 1 from the value of a property of collection 2

here the collection 1 :

```
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "mycode": "1234",
  "field3": "value3"
}
```

here is my collection 2 :

```
{
   "code": "1234",
   "label": "myLabel"
}
```

I want to map the 2 collections with mycode of collection1 and code of collection2 to modify the value of mycode

here is the expected result :

```
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "mycode": "myLabel",
  "field3": "value3"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do an aggregation pipeline in a way
**1st step** - map `mycode` in `collection1` with `code` in `collection2`
**2nd step** - `$unwind` to take looked up part out of the array
**3rd step** - set the `mycode` value to `label` and showing `field1`,`field3` and hiding `_id`(if needed)

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TiXpMITxPQ_)

```js
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "collection2",
      "localField": "mycode",
      "foreignField": "code",
      "as": "mycode"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$mycode"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "field1": 1,
      "field3": 1,
      "_id": 0,
      "mycode": "$mycode.label"
    }
  }
])
```